# Give a subspace of $\mathbb R_l \times \mathbb R_l$ that has no countable dense subset [relative to the subspace topology].

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, second-countable

Let $\mathbb R_l$ be $\mathbb R$ given the lower limit topology, i.e. the topology generated by $\{[a, b) \subseteq \mathbb R|a<b\}$.

Give a subspace of $\mathbb R_l \times \mathbb R_l$ that has no countable dense subset [relative to the subspace topology].

Can anyone help me on this? Our professor did not discuss about countable dense subset.

Comment: Where did the comments go?

Comment: It was a separate question @BenjaminMoss.

Answer (score 2):

Space $\Bbb R_l$ is called Sorgenfrey arrow and it has some exotic properties, making it a useful counterexample, sometimes it is even called a “universal counterexample”. For instance, although the space $\Bbb R_l$ is hereditarily separable, hereditarily Lindelöf, and perfectly normal, its square $\Bbb R_l\times\Bbb R_l$ is non-normal and contains a discrete subspace $\{(x,-x):x\in\Bbb R\}$ of cardinality $\frak c$.

Comment: In what way $\mathbb R_l \times \mathbb R_l $ contains the discrete subspace $\{(x, -x):x \in \mathbb R \}$?

Comment: @FlickerBeat This discrete subspase is closed and looks like a diagonal going from the top-left to the bottom-right. For each $x\in\Bbb R$ a point $(x,-x)$ of this diagonal is located in the bottom-riight corner of its neighborhood $[x+1)\times [-x+1)$, which intersects this diagonal only at the point $(x,-x)$, so this point is isolated in the subspace.

Comment: Is it $[x+1) \times [-x+1)$ or $[x,1) \times [-x,1)$?

Comment: @FlickerBeat Oops, $[x,x+1)\times [-x,-x+1)$.

Comment: Thank you. I think I got it.....